# ML. Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

Tags: error-handling, ml

I have this code:

```
datatype ('a, 'b) alterlist = nil | :: of ('a*'b) * ('a, 'b) alterlist; 
infixr 5 :: 

fun build4(x, one, y, two) = (x,one)::(y,two);
```

and I get this error:

```
datatype ('a,'b) alterlist = :: of ('a * 'b) * ('a,'b) alterlist | nil 
stdIn:41.30-41.46 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]   
operator domain: ('Z * 'Y) * ('Z,'Y) alterlist   
operand:  ('Z * 'Y) * ('X * 'W)   
in expression:
        (x,one) :: (y,two)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of `alterlist`, the constructor `::` takes a tuple as an argument:

```
:: of ('a*'b) * ('a, 'b) alterlist
```

When you construct an `alterlist` using the `::` constructor, you should call it with one value of type `('a*'b)` and another value of type `('a, 'b) alterlist`.

You're trying to call `::` with `(x,one)` and `(y,two)` which are both pairs. One way to fix this would be:

```
fun build4(x, one, y, two) = (x,one) :: ((y,two)::nil)
```

since `((y,two)::nil)` is an alterlist.

Note that the type of argument to `::` is actually `('a*'b) * ('a, 'b) alterlist` which is a pair. ML has no concept of multiple arguments to functions or constructors, instead you pass tuples. With an infix operator this can be a little confusing as the compiler does some syntactic sugar for you.

Given a function like

```
fun f (x, y) = (* ... *)
```

You can call it normally like `f (a, b)` or `f pair` where `pair` is some pair... if you declare it to be infix, you can do `a f b` but this is just syntactic sugar for calling it with a pair.